# Why is this program to delete nth node in linked list is running infintely?

Tags: c, loops, data-structures

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node{
  int data;
  struct node* next;

};
void insert(int x);
void print();

void deletenode(int n);
struct node* head;     //global declaration
int main(){
  int n,m;
  insert(5);
  insert(9);
  insert(2);
  insert(3);  //list is 3,2,9,5;
  print();
  printf("enter the node position you want to delete");
  scanf("%d",&n);
```

calling deletenode function to delete the node

```
  deltenode(n);
```

again printing the list after deletion of nth node

```
   print();
```

guys this program is running efficiently when i am not using `deletenode` function and printing the linked list correctly but after using `deletenode` function when i am using `print` function it is printing infinitely 
i think there should be no mistake in `print` function because it is working fine when i am using it above `deletenode` but after using it below `deletenode` printing infinitely
i am entering or parsing  all the valid values so i am not making any special case in any function
my delete funtion is

```
    void deletenode(int n){
     struct node *temp,*temp1;
     temp=head;
     for(int i=0;i<=n-2;i++){
        temp=temp->next;


    }
    temp1=temp->next;
    temp=temp1->next;
    free(temp1);

    }
```

my print function is

```
 void print(){
 struct node* temp;
 temp=head;
 while(temp!=NULL)
 {   printf("%d",temp->data);
 temp=temp->next;

 }
```

I know this is not the most efficient way to do things, but i would really love a pointer to where i made an error
my insert function is

```
void insert(int x){
struct node *temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(head));
temp->data=x;
temp->next=head;
head=temp; 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function call `deltenode(n);` `(spelling mistake)` is wrong. It should be  `deletenode(n);`.

Also there is some mistakes in your `void deletenode(int n);` function. `temp=temp1->next;` is wrong .It should be `temp->next=temp1->next;` . Then only you skip `temp1`*(n th Node)* from the Linked list.

Modified `void deletenode(int n);` function :-

```
void deletenode(int n)
{
  struct node *temp, *temp1;
  temp = head;
  for (int i = 0; i <= n - 2; i++)
  {
    temp = temp->next;
  }
  temp1 = temp->next;
  temp->next = temp1->next; // not temp=temp1->next;
  free(temp1);
}
```

**Output :-**

```
3295enter the node position you want to delete2
325
```

You have to improve your `printf` statements with necessary `whitespace` and `\n` . Your code fails to delete the `0 th` node. Improve your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your Delete method has an error. The code sequence

```
temp1=temp->next;
temp=temp1->next;
free(temp1);
```

frees the element temp1 but it does not update your linked list correctly. You don't update the temp->next pointer of the element before your deleted element. It should look like this:

```
void deltenode(int n) {
    struct node *previous, *elemtToDelete;
    previous = head;

    // check if the element to delete is your head
    if (n == 0) {
        elemtToDelete = head;
        head = elemtToDelete->next;
    } else {
        // walk through the list to get the previous element.
        for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {
            previous = previous->next;
        }

        elemtToDelete = previous->next;

        struct node *after  = elemtToDelete->next;
        previous->next = after;
    }

    free(elemtToDelete);
}
```